# Abstracting surounding markup structure

Tags: twig

### Problem

I have multiple sections that will have the same markup, like this

```
<div class="A B C">
  <h3 class"D">Section Title 1</h3>

  Some HTML content...
<div>

<div class="A B C">
  <h3 class"D">Section Title 2</h3>

  Some different HTML content...
<div>

<div class="A B C">
  <h3 class"D">Section Title 3</h3>

  Some even different HTML content...
<div>
```

So all the sections share some structure - the surrounding container (`<div class="A B C">`) and heading element (`<h3 class="D">`) - but also have unique content.

Is there a mechanism in Twig to somehow abstract the section creation so that classes *A, B, C, D* are defined only in 1 place?

### Example solution

Ideal solution would be declaring some kind of block-like-macro:

```
{% blockLikeMacro section(title) %}
  <div class="A B C">
    <h3 class"D">{{ title }}</h3>
    {% content %}
  <div>
{% endBlockLikeMacto %}
```

And use it like that:

```
{% blockLikeMacroUse section("Section Title 1") %}
  Some content..
{% endBlockLikeMacroUse %}

{% blockLikeMacroUse section("Section Title 2") %}
  Some different content..
{% endBlockLikeMacroUse %}

{% blockLikeMacroUse section("Section Title 3") %}
  Some event different content..
{% endBlockLikeMacroUse %}
```

### Question

Is such effect (abstract section structure) in any way possible using Twig?

Comment: You could use an `include`, a `macro` or horizontal reuse with `use`

Comment: @DarkBee How is it possible using a `macro`? By defining 2 macros: `macro sectionStart` and `macro sectionEnd`?

Comment: @DarkBee  Also how would I use "parametrize" `include` to give me different title and content each time?

Comment: `{% include "block.twig" with { 'title': section.title, 'content' : section.content, } %}` ?

Comment: Actually `embed` does exactly what I need (https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/embed.html).

Comment: Ah yes forgot about that, that one is able to overwrite blocks :)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can use a loop to iterate over your sections:

```
{% for section in sections %}
    <div class="A B C">
        <h3 class"D">{{ section.title }}</h3>
        {{ section.content }}
    <div>
{% endfor %}
```

Twig also does have support for macros: https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/macro.html

Comment: That's a valid answer, thanks, but I don't find it clean enough. It would mean declaring a `sections` object, which would get quite ugly if the inner content of each section is big.

Comment: I'm not sure how the size of the content makes defining an section object ugly, considering that the content is simply a string that can be stored in a single property on the object. If the content has several disparate parts, then the content might warrant its own class of which an instance would be assigned to the section object.

Comment: The content is HTML markup (with nested tags), so declaring it as a string is far from pretty.

Comment: I'm curious, if you are not pulling this content from a database field, in which case it would already be a string (not that I condone storing HTML in the database), or building the content HTML by concatenating strings, how are you getting this content? The only way I would think this to be possible would be to have several disparate data points of which the content is comprised. In that case, it would be optimal for those data points to be encapsulated within a content class, and rendered within a Twig template.

Comment: Currently I'm having all my content hard-coded in the template file.

Comment: Ah, yes, I suppose I didn't think that someone would be hard-coding content.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145982/discussion-between-robert-and-jjones).

Comment: {% set content %}
This is your html
<br />Foobar
<br />Lipsum
{% endset %}

Comment: You define HTML blockwise like the comment I made above, the markup here is stripping my newlines  though